# the transition of a <div> creates a border on an other element

Tags: html, css, border, transition

If you hover between the two borders, you'll get an ugly (but very small) border around them. Can someone help me (and please explain me why I get this result)? I tried to set a transparent border on every element - but with no effect.

Best regards,
Sandro

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.content .line-left {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #286090;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content .line-left::after {
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
 position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content .line-right {
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #286090;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
}

.content .line-right::after {
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.content:hover .line-left::after, .content:hover .line-right::after {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 2s cubic-bezier(.15,.65,1,.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="line-left"></div>
  <div class="line-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no border in your code. see my screenshot. https://prnt.sc/mbgagf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a rendring issue. Here is another idea to obtain the same effect without issue and with less of code. We define 4 lines with gradient: two on each side and at the same position. On hover we simply decrease the height of the grey ones and we increase the height of the blue ones. The `top`/`bottom` will define the direction of the animation:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background:
    linear-gradient(#286090,#286090) bottom 0 right 25px,
    linear-gradient(#bfbfbf,#bfbfbf) top    0 right 25px,
    linear-gradient(#286090,#286090) top    0 left  25px,
    linear-gradient(#bfbfbf,#bfbfbf) bottom 0 left  25px;
  background-size:3px 0, 3px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:2s cubic-bezier(.15, .65, 1, .15);
}

.content:hover {
  background-size:3px 100%, 3px 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="content">
</div>
```